# Magento Magmi Multiselect import

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magmi

I can't seem to get the Magmi version: 0.7.22 (just upgraded) to import multiple values into a multiselect attribute.

This is my source file

```
attribute_set|type|sku|testcolor|supplier|size
default|Simple|2-ALN2320|"Red , Blue"|Flint|89
```

it loads the supplier & size fine.. 
But the testcolor is a multiselect type and it does not work.. 
I tried to use

```
attribute_set|type|sku|testcolor:multiple:1|supplier|size
default|Simple|2-ALN2320|"Red,Blue"|Flint|89
```

That also did not work
I don't see any errors in progress.txt

ANY idea on what I am missing?

Answer (score 4):

Are you using Magento 1.9.3?

There was some change in the Multiselect backend type and magmi is failing. Try to apply this patch [MAGMI multiselect issue with Magento 1.9.3](http://magehelperblog.com/magmi-multiselect-issue-magento-1-9-3/)  that worked for me.

Just copy and replace the file `magmi_defaultattributehandler.php` into folder `magmi/plugins/inc`.